# How to find cgroup memory limit in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: command-line, 22.04, systemd, ram, cgroup

Using VERSION="22.04 LTS" and trying to find the memory limit which memory.limit_in_bytes or memory.max' gives. However, it looks there is no '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes' and no '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.max'

```
ls: cannot access '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.max': No such file or directory
```

Then what metrics will be availble that can be alternative to those cgroup metrics in Ubuntu 22.04LTS?

Comment: What do you mean by system memory limit? The maximum RAM your computer's motherboard can support? The maximum RAM Ubuntu can theoretically support?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, thanks for the follow up. It is the memory that a cgroup allows for a process or group of processes as in my understanding, one cgroup namespace could have multiple process in a hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that, generally, there is no such limit that is imposed by the Ubuntu operating system by default, but you can set that limit manually ... Similarly, some applications that you install like virtualization/containers services might set that for their child processes by default.

That said, you can monitor memory usage for cgroups with [`systemd-cgtop`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/systemd-cgtop.1.html) which looks like this:

```
Control Group                                Tasks   %CPU   Memory  Input/s Output/s
/                                             1643    7.0     6.2G        -        -
user.slice                                    1331    6.9    10.2G        -        -
user.slice/user-1000.slice                    1331    6.9     9.8G        -        -
user.slice/use…000.slice/user@1000.service    1319    6.9     9.8G        -        -
system.slice                                   177    0.2     3.2G        -        -
system.slice/systemd-oomd.service                1    0.1     1.7M        -        -
system.slice/containerd.service                 13    0.0    60.2M        -        -
system.slice/NetworkManager.service              4    0.0     9.5M        -        -
system.slice/thermald.service                    3    0.0     2.8M        -        -
system.slice/fail2ban.service                    5    0.0    20.9M        -        -
system.slice/nmbd.service                        1    0.0     4.5M        -        -
system.slice/epmd.service                        1    0.0   428.0K        -        -
system.slice/fwupd.service                       6    0.0   111.5M        -        -
system.slice/cups.service                        1    0.0     3.5M        -        -
system.slice/apache2.service                     6    0.0    23.3M        -        -
dev-hugepages.mount                              -      -    24.0K        -        -
dev-mqueue.mount                                 -      -     8.0K        -        -
init.scope                                       1      -    14.9M        -        -
proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount                    -      -     4.0K        -        -
```

The max limits, however, you can view for system slice under `/sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/` and its sub directories like for example:

```
$ head /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/memory.max 
max
$
$
$ head /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/*/memory.max
==> /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/accounts-daemon.service/memory.max <==
max

==> /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/acpid.service/memory.max <==
max

==> /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/apache2.service/memory.max <==
max

==> /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/atd.service/memory.max <==
max

==> /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/auditd.service/memory.max <==
max

==> /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/avahi-daemon.service/memory.max <==
max

==> /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/bluetooth.service/memory.max <==
max

...
```

... and similarly under `/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/` for user slice.

The same info can be queried for each individual systemd unit with [`systemctl show`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemctl.html#show%20PATTERN%E2%80%A6%7CJOB%E2%80%A6) like for example:

```
$ systemctl show networkd-dispatcher.service | grep '^Memory'
MemoryCurrent=16449536
MemoryAvailable=infinity
MemoryAccounting=yes
MemoryMin=0
MemoryLow=0
MemoryHigh=infinity
MemoryMax=infinity
MemorySwapMax=infinity
MemoryZSwapMax=infinity
MemoryLimit=infinity
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=no
```

Where, in the above output, `max`, `infinity` or equivalent mean no-limit